# How do I specify an index using a Kibana query?

Tags: kibana

How does one create a Kibana query that uses a specific index?

I've tried using

- `_type:stats AND index:prod`
- `_type:stats AND _index:prod`
- `_type:stats AND _index_:prod`

all with no luck.

I have the main dashboard index set to `_all` and if I do a terms panel, I see the prod index so i know it's visible.

Comment: is this about dashboard object?

Comment: Yes. I'm specifically talking about the "query" box at the top.

Comment: looks like index field is not indexed! "This field is present in your elasticsearch mapping but not in any documents in the search results. You may still be able to visualize or search on it.